# kubernetes CNI (container networking interface)

Tags: networking, kubernetes, cni

I am new to kubernetes world, Can someone specify/tell/redirect as to:
what is Kubernetes CNI? 
why is it used? 
what are its usecases? 
what are the best CNI plugins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go through following blogs to understand what is CNI and why it is used:

https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-and-cni-whats-next-making-it-easier-to-write-networking-plugins/

Following link has some good information about different type of CNI plugins available and when to use what:

https://chrislovecnm.com/kubernetes/cni/choosing-a-cni-provider/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed was very helpful links to kick-start working with Kubernetes CNI.